# PowerShell to list of UPNs based on specific Wildcard search

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, office365, windows-scripting

I need to modify the below script, which is partially working.

It basically queries the Office 365 Users, Contact, Groups and Deleted users, and then match it with the user input, then display it on Out-GridView when found.

```
Try { 
    Install-Module MSOnline -ErrorAction Stop
    Import-Module MSOnline -ErrorAction Stop 

    $UserCredential = Get-Credential
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
}
Catch { Write-Warning "Unable to load Microsoft Office 365 module because $($Error[0])"; Exit }

$UPN = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the User Principal Name to search (wildcard accepted)"
If ($UPN) {
    $UPN = $search
    $MSOLActiveUsers = Get-MsolUser -All
    $MSOLDeletedUsers = Get-MsolUser -All -ReturnDeletedUsers
    $MSOLGroups = Get-MsolGroup -All
    $MSOLContacts = Get-MsolContact -All
    $MSOLRecipients = Get-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited​

    $MSOLCombinedResults = $MSOLActiveUsers + $MSOLDeletedUsers + $MSOLGroups + $MSOLContacts + $MSOLRecipients
    ​
    $MSOLCombinedResults | Where-Object { $_.emailaddresses -match $search -or $_.emailaddress -match $search -or $_.userprincipalname -eq $search -or $_.proxyaddresses -match $search }

    Switch ($MSOLCombinedResults.Count) {
        0 { Write-Warning "No user account with a SamAccountName matching '$($UPN)' found!" }
        1 { $MSOLCombinedResults }
        default { $MSOLCombinedResults | Out-GridView -Title "Please select a user" -OutputMode Single }
    }
}
```

The issue with the above script is the result is always meaningless long Gridview?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the content of `$MSOLCombinedResults[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: your script is missing connecting to Exchange Online, which is required for `Get-Recipient` but I assume you did this, but just forgot to add to your question.

---

First of all, you filter `$MSOLCombinedResults` in this line:

```
 $MSOLCombinedResults | Where-Object (...)
```

But then you pipe to `Out-GridView` unfiltered array:

```
$MSOLCombinedResults | Out-GridView (...)
```

What you forgot is to save filtered array and then operate on it. PowerShell doesn't do that automatically, so you should go with something like:

```bsh
$filteredResults = $MSOLCombinedResults | Where-Object { $_.emailaddresses -match $search -or $_.emailaddress -match $search -or $_.userprincipalname -eq $search -or $_.proxyaddresses -match $search }

Switch ($filteredResults .Count) {
  # do something
}
```

Another thing is that `$MSOLCombinedResults` contains multiple types of object, so you should select desired properties before outputting it (for performance reasons it'd be nice to select them even earlier).

The data you'd be interested in is as follows:

- From `Get-MsolUser`: UserPrincipalName (string), ProxyAddresses (array)
- From `Get-MsolGroup`: EmailAddress (string), ProxyAddresses (array)
- From `Get-MsolContact`: EmailAddress (string), ProxyAddresses (array, optional as I don't see this value set usually)
- From `Get-Recipient`: EmailAddress**es** (array, notice plural), ExternalEmailAddress (string in `SMTP:xxx` format), PrimarySmtpAddress (string)

You have to modify your filter accordingly and then output desired results using `Select-Object` to `Out-GridView`. Take a look at [calculated properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) as you might want to *rename/convert* some properties for easier filtering.